# google plus photo animation with css3 or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-plus

**so heres the animation**

[image]

into

[image]

**and this one**

[image]

how can they do that?
1. re-size animation
2. stack and animate.

just CSS3 ? any example?

Thanks

Adam Ramadhan

Comment: Consider putting a comment when downvoting any question on SO it will help the peer to improve the question and will get his question answered and in turn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question:

1. To resize and make image animate ( zoom in effect ) you should use something like :

   ```
   ul#pics li:hover {
       -moz-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(0deg);
       -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(0deg);
       -o-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(0deg);
       -ms-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(0deg);
       transform: scale(1.1) rotate(0deg);
   }
   ```
2. For stack and animate, you should use CSS3 and jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

On my machine using Chrome, I see a CSS3 `-webkit-transform`. Since that's the only `transform` they're using, it must be detecting that my browser is webkit and choosing the right way to transform. They probably have various other techniques for other browsers.

However, there's no jQuery fallback, as the page doesn't use jQuery; there's probably a different JavaScript fallback developed by Google though.

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://random.tommicarleman.net/gallery/) something you are looking for?